# MariaDB Parallel Replication setup

Tags: replication, mariadb, master-slave

I am trying to experiment the parallel replication setup of `MariaDB` with the latest version 10.x

However, I couldn't understand where to pass the mentioned settings/variables and what are the optimum settings which I should use for Production from the [official doc](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/parallel-replication/).

Where to configure the `slave-parallel-threads=#` in master `my.cnf`? I using `my.cnf.d/server.cnf` for all settings. What are the recommended `slave-parallel` modes and where should I set them?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MariaDB 10.0.5+ you need to set:

on master:
binlog_commit_wait_usec = 20000
binlog_commit_wait_count = 50

on slave(s):
slave_parallel_threads = 16

Obviously you have to adjust the numbers depending on your workload.

This is slave-parallel-mode=minimal (but you don't need to set it, it's implied)

For more effective slave-parallel-mode(s) you need to use MariaDB 10.1.3+ which is not GA yet (May/2015).